# Tags to watch out for, when coding for all browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

SO I coded a website and it looks and works great in Chrome.
Testing it in Mozilla: some animations (transitions) aren't looking right.
And Safari and IE are completely wrong (border radius not showing, No transitions, formatting all wrong).

Could someone point me to a list of TAGS in CSS which don't work between browsers ...or..
Do I have to transfer most of the code to JS, due to my abuse of CSS.

note: I primarily use % to dimension my boxes. eg (60% and 40% boxes in a wrapper). I chrome the two boxes appear in one line. In safari and IE, they wrap onto the next line... WHY? not what I want.

//This seems like a question that would be asked before but I can't seem to find much on stackoverflow or other sites

Comment: [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/) might be helpful.

Comment: *`"Do I have to transfer most of the code to JS, due to my abuse of CSS"`* what you mean?

Comment: Regarding your edit, please include relevant portions of your code in your question so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: If your question is about two divs where the second is wrapped into a new line there's already plenty of similar questions here on SO. If you think your case is special, post the needed code to reproduce the issue. Your question is too vague as it currently stands and you're expecting load of subjective answers. When the answer is only one.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan All my animations have been done in CSS (hovers etc.) using the "transition" tag. None of the transitions are working is IE and Safari... will they work if I instead write them in JS? or is there an easier alternative

Comment: Transition will not work in IE8 so you need to start your question with what browsers are you interested in. If you need to add EFX to IE8 than fallback to jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arman,

This list could be quite extensive and complex. Many modern browsers will be able to display most of your HTML5 and CSS3 with some exceptions in which you have to specify -moz-, -webkit-, -ms-, and -o- as a prefix.

In some cases you have to actually hack the browser using other methods such as these [Browser Hacks](http://mynthon.net/howto/-/webdev/CSS-big-list-of-css-hacks.txt)

NAd as showdev suggested, check caniuse.com to be exactly clear on this list you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, question was put on hold as "off-topic" so I imagine I should return with more specific questions. 
I'll learn from those sites which you and others suggested and see how they can help. I'll post specific questions if any are are unanswered by the linked sites.

Comment: Good luck! You will do fine